# Encoding Period in URI

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please excuse me if this question has already been answered on StackOverflow.

I have a server-side service that can be accessed by the following URI:
services/signIn/{email}

The {email} part is where the email goes. The problem is that emails contain a period, and this cannot be URL encoded. Therefore, the service does not work. And, I already tried replacing the period with *%2E*, but it does not work. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode periods for URLs in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938900/how-to-encode-periods-for-urls-in-javascript)

Comment: If unencoded periods don't work, and encoded periods don't work, then there's probably nothing you can do on the client. Without more information about the server, this question isn't really answerable.