# Backbone.js unable to find module if my url contains "period"

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs, web-frontend

I am trying to pass targetURL using get method. This is the URL that i tried: http://localhost:8000/login/auth?targetURL=www.google.com
Backbone.js will return "Cannot GET /login/auth?targetURL=www.google.com"

By right, get variable should not affect the module i'm going into it.
if i remove the "period", the url works well. for e.g : http://localhost:8000/login/auth?targetURL=wwwgooglecom

this is how my routes look like

```
routes: {
        'logout': 'logout',
        ':level1': 'subpageAction',
        'logout/:authFail': 'logout',
        ':level1/:level2': 'subpageAction',
        ':level1/:level2/:level3': 'subpageAction',
        ':level1/:level2/:level3/:level4': 'subpageAction',
        '': 'subpageAction'
    },
```

Does anyone have the same issue? The issue only happen when i put "." in my url.
Anyone can help on this issue?

Comment: Isn't that being handled by your server?

Comment: If `targetURL=www` (without dot) then all works as expected ? If yes, then which version of Backbone are you using ?

Comment: @coding_idiot im using backbone.js 1.1.2. Yes, target URL works without the dots.

Comment: It looks like more a server routing problem than a frontend one

Comment: can you please post Http status code which you can find in network tab of developer tool?

Comment: @nikhilmehta its showing 404 as status code. I really suspect its my server routing issue instead of the frontend. But url rewrite are all enabled and .htaccess are coded correctly.

Comment: @Kimberlee Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298542/apicontroller-returns-404-when-id-contains-period or add <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> in your web config

Comment: Are you using both backbone and react?

Answer (score 1):

You are running into [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) issues.  While W3C standards for form submission declared that the dot didn't need to be substituted with `%2E`, practice is that there are been so many hacks with '..' hiding in form submissions that different layers of software will trip you up rendering even encoding the dot as `%2E` ineffective.

One solution that may work, depending on your exact use case, is to toss a trailing slash to the end of the URL, e.g., `www.google.com/` instead of `www.google.com`.

You might want to look at these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938900/how-to-encode-periods-for-urls-in-javascript) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856693/a-url-resource-that-is-a-dot-2e) as well.   There is no perfect answer here, just near perfect ones.